# why is my Firebase script hanging in the terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing a script to auto update firebase as I need to run this once a week

I have a index.js file and im running `node index.js` to run it, all good

I've commented out lots of the code but for now I'm just running

```
const calculateWinnings = () => {
    console.log('called me!')
    return firebaseApp
        .database()
        .ref(`data`)
        .once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {
            console.log('snaph::', snapshot.val())
            return
        })
}


calculateWinnings()
```

this is doing what I expect in terms of it's running the function and returning me data from firebase

however, the script hangs and never exits in the terminal with the cursor marker showing

when I comment out the firebase stuff, it does what I expect

so I'm wondering how do I exit the script successfully or why is it hanging? I'm return the promise so it should be resolving?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your answer. I haven't been able to look at the code again but I'll try and take a look tonight/weekend and then give your answer feedback. looks like it should work tho!

Comment: Hey Red Baron. Did you get a chance to read my answer below and give it a try?

Comment: I'm actually going to be trying it tonight so will give you feedback then!

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDK performs all network and disk activity in a background thread. When the `calculateWinnings()` returns, the `then((snapshot) => {` hasn't actually been called yet. For this reason it is good that the program doesn't exit yet, or you'd never see the `console.log('snaph::', snapshot.val())`.

You can see this in action, by forcing the program to exit:

```
const calculateWinnings = () => {
    console.log('called me!')
    return firebaseApp
        .database()
        .ref(`data`)
        .once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {
            console.log('snaph::', snapshot.val())
            return
        })
}

calculateWinnings()
process.exit();
```

If you run it like this, you'll see that the snapshot from the database is never logged.

This is also the answer to how to handle it correctly: since you already return the promise from `once()` from your `calculateWinnings` method, you can wait for that to complete and then tell the process to exit:

```
calculateWinnings().then(() => {
  process.exit();
});
```

Or if you're on a more modern Node.js version:

```
const calculateWinnings = async () => {
  ... the function body is the same as you currently have
}

await calculateWinnings()
process.exit();
```

Comment: it didn't seem to work actually, it didnt seem to run any of the code strangely

Comment: If you tried the second/third snippet that's unexpected. Can you update your question to show what you tried?